# C++ Replace given word console application

Tags: c++, replace

I want to replace a word in a sentence with another word.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string str;
getline(cin, str);
cout << "Original text: " << str;
for (int j = 0; j < (int)str.size(); j++) {
    string key = str.substr(j, 7), repl;
    if (key == "ronaldo") {
        repl = "messi";
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            str[j + k] = repl[k];
        }
    }
}
cout << "\nNew text: " << str << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Original --> "The world's best football player ***ronaldo*** will be the champion this year."

New Sentence -> The world's best football player ***messi*** will be the champion this year."
ronaldo --> messi

I get an error when I use str.subst

Comment: what do you think will happen on this line: `string key = str.substr(j, 7), repl;` when `j` is `str.size() - 1`?

Comment: ronaldo --> messido but i want ronaldo-->messi

Comment: _"I get an error"_ What error are you getting?

Comment: I want to change the 7 index of my chosen string (ronaldo). If there is another way can you share it with me?

Comment: wrong output is output
expected -> messi
output-> messido

Answer (score -3):

Just make the word you want to change a string variable and make the user Input the data of the string variable.

Comment: Try to add a code example and maybe elaborate a little. As it is, this answer is not useful.

Comment: Sorry I can but I don't have my laptop on me right now so I'm just on my phone